Why is my discord bot not seeing message content
I wanted to make a discord bot. I turned on the message intent and then got to work. This is my code
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
private DiscordSocketClient _client;

public static void Main(string[] args)
    => new 
Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

public async Task MainAsync()
{
    _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

    _client.Log += LogAsync;

  
    string token =  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bot token is missing. Please set the DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN environment variable.");
        return;
    }

    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
    await _client.StartAsync();

    _client.Ready += () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bot is connected!");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

    
    _client.MessageReceived += MessageReceivedAsync;

    await Task.Delay(-1);
}

private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage message)
{

    if (message.Author.IsBot || message.Author.IsWebhook)
        return;

    
    Console.WriteLine($"Received message: '{message.Content}' from {message.Author.Username}");

    
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Content))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received an empty message.");
        return;
    }

    
    if (message.Content.ToLower().Trim() == "!hello")
    {
        
        await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Hello!");
    }
    else
    {
        
        await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"You said: '{message.Content}'");
    }
}

private Task LogAsync(LogMessage log)
{
    Console.WriteLine(log.ToString());
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
}

Sadly the bot sees the messages as empty. When I write "hello" it prints "got a message : '' from @[redacted]". Can anyone help?
Debugging which got me to the conclusion it sees it as empty and turning on the message intent which didn't do anything

I just had to turn on the intents
public async Task MainAsync()
{
        var config = new DiscordSocketConfig
        {
            GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.Guilds |
                             GatewayIntents.GuildMessages |
                             GatewayIntents.MessageContent
        };
}

